# Python scraping regex (word just next to the number)

Tags: python-3.x, regex, web-scraping

I hope you're well. I'd like to scrape different data with regex :)

```
#Récupération des ingrédients
                try:    
                    ingredients = [item.text.replace("\n", "").strip() for item in soup.find_all("li", {"class": "recipe-ingredients__list__item"})]
                except Exception as e:
                    ingredients = None
```

Here is the json result

```
"ingredients": [
            "250g de porc h\u00e2ch\u00e9 (le filet mignon c'est vraiment bon)",
            "1 oignon blanc",
            "1 carotte",
            "6 champignons parfum\u00e9s chinois (pas des champignons noirs)",
            "1poign\u00e9e de vermicelles de riz (cheveux d'ange)",
            "1poign\u00e9e de germes de soja",
            "3 oeufs",
            "2gousses d'ail",
            "Galette de riz vietnamiennes (les grandes)",
            "4cuill\u00e8res \u00e0 soupe de nuoc mam",
            "Poivre"
```

Do you how I can scrape separately
the quantity (here is the number)
the quantifying (which always sticks to the number when it exists)
the name of the ingredient

I do not find how to do it with regex

Thanks for your response @Ryszard Czech :) it's the first time use regex. If I want to save directly the separated data in json:

what should be the code something like that?

```
#Récupération des ingrédients
            try:    
                ingredients = [item.text.replace("\n", "").strip() for item in soup.find_all("li", {"class": "recipe-ingredients__list__item"}, [re.compile(r'^(?:(\d+)([^\W\d_]*))?(.*)', x), for x in ingredients])]
            except Exception as e:
                ingredients = None
```

Or do I need to use some pattern to apply to ingredients

Comment: example breakdown of this -> `the quantity (here is the number) the quantifying (which always sticks to the number when it exists) the name of the ingredient` , handy, yes ?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand what you mean?

An example could be like this:
-250
-g 
-de porc h\u00e2ch\u00e9 (le filet mignon c'est vraiment bon)

or something like this 
-3
-Null 
-oeufs

Comment: example of what eeze handy, yes ?

Comment: Please kindly upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
import json, re
j="""{"ingredients": [
            "250g de porc h\u00e2ch\u00e9 (le filet mignon c'est vraiment bon)",
            "1 oignon blanc",
            "1 carotte",
            "6 champignons parfum\u00e9s chinois (pas des champignons noirs)",
            "1poign\u00e9e de vermicelles de riz (cheveux d'ange)",
            "1poign\u00e9e de germes de soja",
            "3 oeufs",
            "2gousses d'ail",
            "Galette de riz vietnamiennes (les grandes)",
            "4cuill\u00e8res \u00e0 soupe de nuoc mam",
            "Poivre"]}"""
jsObj = json.loads(j)
print( [re.findall(r'^(?:(\d+)([^\W\d_]*))?(.*)', x) for x in jsObj["ingredients"]] )
```

Output:

```
[[('250', 'g', " de porc hâché (le filet mignon c'est vraiment bon)")], [('1', '', ' oignon blanc')], [('1', '', ' carotte')], [('6', '', ' champignons parfumés chinois (pas des champignons noirs)')], [('1', 'poignée', " de vermicelles de riz (cheveux d'ange)")], [('1', 'poignée', ' de germes de soja')], [('3', '', ' oeufs')], [('2', 'gousses', " d'ail")], [('', '', 'Galette de riz vietnamiennes (les grandes)')], [('4', 'cuillères', ' à soupe de nuoc mam')], [('', '', 'Poivre')]]
```

The `^(?:(\d+)([^\W\d_]*))?(.*)` expression matches optionally one or more digits (capture 1) and an optional letters after (capture 2), and then captures the rest into capture 3.

Comment: Thks a lot Ryszard :) How I can implement it directly in my code when I save the data ingredients in my json 

#Récupération des ingrédients
            try:    
                ingredients = [item.text.replace("\n", "").strip() for item in soup.find_all("li", {"class": "recipe-ingredients__list__item"})]
            except Exception as e:
                ingredients = None

Comment: @LouisDsm I think it is just the same, can't you just replace the `x` input with the variable in your code? Replace `item.text.replace("\n", "").strip()` with `re.findall(r'^(?:(\d+)([^\W\d_]*))?(.*)', item.text.replace("\n", "").strip())`

Comment: who know's where I can learn and create my regex (like a generator?)

Comment: I've some other json to correct with juste a space after the number :) and some without number and quantifying, something pretty similar 

            "3\u2009\u00be cups water",
            "1\u2009\u2153 cups uncooked brown rice",
            "2 cloves garlic",
            "1   bay leaf",
            "\u00bc teaspoon salt",
            "4 ounces thinly sliced prosciutto, chopped",
            "4 ounces mozzarella cheese, diced",
            "\u00bc cup chopped fresh basil",

Comment: @LouisDsm You can try with `re.findall(r'^(?:(\d+)\s*([^\W\d_]*))?(.*)', item.text.replace("\n", "").strip())`, `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters. Try http://regex.inginf.units.it/ to generate a pattern based on string(s).

Comment: Thks it works well. I went on the website :) really lice